# Laravel blade file after if() condition using my blade file become code highleter color all changed

Tags: php, laravel-5, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, laravel-blade

[This is my laravel blade file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ybwn.jpg)

when i using if() Condition in my code, after all lines code highlighter are not showing properly.

Comment: please mention your code here and explain what exact problem you have,

Comment: i think this is not an issue. because your IDE doesn't have laravel's blade library. thats why you didn't see proper highlighting in your code.